# Is there a way to wrap / inject / normalize code in ASP.Net Core Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API application and all my controllers look like this (simplified name and just one service)

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> A ()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await _serviceA.GetA());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> B()
        {
            try
            {
               return Ok(await _serviceB.GetB());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The call gets recieved and goes into the service, if anything goes wrong in the service I return a BadRequest with the message for the front-end

As you might have spotted, I always have to type the `try catch` block with the return statement in every call in every controller. I was wondering if there is a way to wrap / inject / normalize the code inside the `try` block for every controller request with a configuration? (and possibly make multiple custom "wrappers" for different scenario's / controllers)

I was thinking of a solution where the `try catch` would be wrapped around the service call (`return Ok(await _serviceA.GetA());` for example - or even just `await _serviceA.GetA()` if possible) so that I only have to write `return Ok(await _serviceA.GetA());` or `await _serviceA.GetA()` in the endpoints in the controller and the other `try catch` logic (including the return statement) would be done in this "wrapper"

Kind regards

Comment: Instead of wrapping the exceptions in the service, you can try implementing Exception handling Middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-handler

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue ?